# Keep worksheet on screen (to work on it) once closing the form (Menu to select a sheet)

Tags: excel, vba, forms

I am running VBA code to display a menu.
There are a few command buttons, each selecting a different worksheet (I do locks/unlocks of select sheet) for user to work on.
Once completed on the worksheet, I have a macro button on the worksheet that re-displays the menu. This works.

I cannot get the worksheet to remain open on the screen. The program seems to stop.

Code thus far:
This is 1-Commandbutton that should open a worksheet to work on the history data

```vb
Private Sub cmdRPTSRVHIST_Click()
  
  Unload MAINMENU

 `Deactivate MAINMENU`   
  `Close MAINMENU`  
  `Worksheets("QRYsrvHst").Select`  
  `ActiveSheet.Name = "QrysrvHST"`  

      Sheets("Qrysrvhst").Visible = True
      Sheets("Qrysrvhst").Activate

       MsgBox ("**   what now????"), vbYesNo
    
  `'** once I click OK on MSGBOX, the pgm stops (cannot see worksheet)`
  `** seems to go back to programmer edit mode (ALT-F11)`
  `NOTE: Calling/running pgm out of ALT-F11/F5-run - might this be an issue??`

End Sub
```

Comment: Unload, Deactivate and then Close seems a bit overkill, and in the wrong order. Unload by itself is enough.

Comment: You select a worksheet and then immediately rename it, but the next lines refer to the old name. Its just a change in capitalization, but its still a strange thing to do,.

Answer (score 0):

If you run a script from the VB Project editor, then the application returns to the editor after execution has ended. It won't happen when the user runs the script outside of the editor.